# Implement Cache in Azure Service Fabric

Tags: azure, caching, azure-service-fabric, stateful

I am working on a project in which I **need a set of data frequently** and currently for getting that data I have to make call to 3rd party Service which is taking lot of time.So what I want is to **maintain a local cache**.The Data is **modified very infrequently or is almost constant**.What is the best way of implementing this in Azure Service Fabric.I am currently thinking of making the **Microservice stateful**. Is is the best way to do this?When node goes down it should copy its local cache to other node.If making it stateful is good than How should i go on implementing this?

Comment: What behavior does the cache need? Should the data be stored or is it no problem if the data is lost but just a performance drop?

Comment: @WouterB Data should be stored and should not be lost..

Comment: If your information should not be lost a reliable collection if probably your best bet. A little bit dependent on the size of the data. If it turns out that the performance is too low you could also "cache" it by using runtime variables which are backed up by your reliable collections.

Comment: @WouterB Should I create singleton partition?

Comment: That depends how big your data is. If your data is big and you need to access it a lot it's probably a good idea to partition your service.

Comment: Store it in MSSQL server. No need to over complicate it early on! Has great support for geo data too.

Comment: @WouterB Is reading from Reliable Collection slow as compared to reading from Runtime Variables?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you have two options:
If you need performance and geografical cache data replication, you can use a redis cache.

The other option is use reliable dictionary's.  It's a service fabric feature, and reliable dictionary's are replicated to other nodes.

You can only access the reliable dictionary in a service fabric statefull context.

Example bellow:

```
IReliableDictionary<string, string> Dictionary = await this.StateManager.GetOrAddAsync<IReliableDictionary<string, string>>("stringlistcache");
    using (var tx = this.StateManager.CreateTransaction())
    {   
        await pingDictionary.AddOrUpdateAsync(tx, "testkey", "testvalue", (key, value) => "testvalue");
        cachedValue = await Dictionary.TryGetValueAsync(tx, "testkey");
        await Dictionary.TryRemoveAsync(tx, "testkey");
        await tx.CommitAsync();     
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is quite old, but for those looking for a solution today, you can use this open source project:

http://service-fabric-distributed-cache.socreate.it

you can also find it on GitHub here:
https://github.com/SoCreate/service-fabric-distributed-cache