# Caching and refreshing database in a stateful service

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2017, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateful

I've got a *stateless* service which simply allows READ operations against a remote database.

In order to remove the bottleneck of traffic to a remote resources, I'd like to cache the database locally, especially since it is very low transaction volume and a small dataset - around 10 megabytes.

I still need to be able to perform SET operations, such as JOINS against the data.

**Does Service Fabric specify how to periodically cache a data source such as SQL Server?**

I know there may be different ways to skin this cat, but I don't want to have to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: Does anything else change this database?

Comment: @MickyD maybe once per day or so, but yes there are other "writers" to the database

Comment: Could try Azure Redis cache with a suitable expiry

Comment: we're running on premises

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implement Cache in Azure Service Fabric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44699720/implement-cache-in-azure-service-fabric).  That or just use Entity Framework's `Load()` method, assuming you are using EF

Comment: You could also use `MemoryCache` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

The SF platform (as in Stateful services) doesn't provide a way to do set based operations atm.

But, you could simply run a database server (like MySQL /SQL Server) inside a [container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-containers-overview) on the cluster. Combined with read-through caching from the stateless service.